# Which version is correct, 脚趾甲 or 脚指甲?

Tags: vocabulary

My question is as the title. I have seen both versions as the Chinese equivalent of "toenail". Which one is correct? Or are both right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both 脚趾 and 脚指 mean *toe*.

[趾](http://www.zdic.net/z/25/js/8DBE.htm) means *toe* and [指](http://www.zdic.net/z/1a/xs/6307.htm) means *finger*, and historically 脚趾 is the correct term, but because 指 is a homophone and has a very similar meaning, 脚指 is such a common mistake that in modern contexts, it could be considered correct also.

Note that this only applies to the 脚趾/脚指 pair; if you only write 指甲, it would mean "fingernail".

Answer (score 1):

“趾甲” is short for "脚趾甲" which is toenail.